# Why does a string of arabic characters crash Safari and other web browsers?

Tags: macos, ios, mac, safari, crash

I was reading an article about a problem with Mac and iOS. Why does this string of Arabic characters

[image]

crash Mac computers running Safari?

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/08/rendering-bug-crashes-os-x-and-ios-apps-with-string-of-arabic-characters/

Comment: Well... it hasn't been fixed in iOS 8.3 - just confirmed that it resets a phone and when done properly, can totally lock a users Messaging app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the arstechnia link to ycombinator page states, it is a "bug inside Apples CoreText font rendering framework".

This post on a Russian website drew attention to it:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/191654/

(translated page here: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fpost%2F191654%2F )

The comments under the ycombinator article are the most interesting, with one reader pointing out that this bug is already fixed in Mavericks

Also, if I had enough reputation, I would downvote your question for putting an offending string in the question and thus risks causing a crash for some apple.stackexchange.com readers.  A slightly malicious or somewhat stupid move on your part, I dare say.

Comment: Luckily, the site has editors on and Daniel Lawson was able to edit out the offending string so that all viewers of the home page don't experience a crash. If you want to see the crash yourself - select the edit button on the main question and look at the original text of the question. Save your work in Safari first!